# Would there be a shorter version of this part of code in JS / CSS / HTML programming?

Tags: javascript, html, css

A question in JS / CSS / HTML programming!

Again, I'm not good at asking the question pinpoint, and sorry for all the confusion. I shall talk about my real intention for this part of code, and see what solutions can be made.

I'd like to invite the users to input characters, which will be thrown into part of the variable `characters` for another function `create_random_string()`.

If that's the case, what solutions can be made to shorten the code for the part `document.addEventListener()` for the sake of efficiency? Thank you very much!

```
var characters = '';
function create_random_string(string){
  var random_string = '';
  for (var i, i = 0; i < string; i++) {
     random_string += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
  }
  return random_string; 
} 

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if(event.key == "a") {
    characters += "a";
  }
  else if(event.key == "b") {
    characters += "b";
  }
  else if(event.key == "c") {
    characters += "c";
  }
...
  else if(event.key == "x") {
    characters += "x";
  }
  else if(event.key == "y") {
    characters += "y";
  }
  else if(event.key == "z") {
    characters += "z";
  }
```

Comment: How about `console.log(event.key)`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I should talk about the `character` thing rather than the `console.log()` stuff . If that's the case, any reduction can be made for the code? Thank you so much!

Comment: When you post a question, you should take great care to make sure that the question accurately reflects what it is you want to know, or to understand. It is a waste of people's time to post an inaccurate question.

Comment: Yes, I'll bear that in mind! Thank you for your advice! @Pointy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not check for a range of keys:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key >= 'a' && event.key <= 'z'){
    console.log(event.key);
  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I should talk about the `character` thing rather than the `console.log()` . If that's the case, any reduction can be made for the code? Thank you so much!

Comment: Just replace `console.log(event.key);` with `characters += event.key`!

Answer (score 0):

`e` is [Event Object](https://%5Bevents%5D(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)). [`.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) is an Event property that gets the key that was tapped. When testing a key event make sure to click the testing area to gain focus first.

```js
document.onkeydown = logKey;

function logKey(e) {
  console.log(e.key);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I should talk about the `character` thing rather than coming up the `console.log()` . If that's the case, any reduction can be made for the code? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this that's even shorter than the other answers:

```js
document.onkeydown = (e) => console.log(e.key);
```

This uses an inline function to further reduce the length of the answer by [zer00ne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72393774/6456163).

If you are more interested in form validation than just logging to the console, you can also do something along the lines of the following:

```js
function alphaOnly(event) {
  let key = event.keyCode;
  return ((key >= 65 && key <= 90) || key == 8);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for such your patience! I'm sorry that I should talk about the `character` thing rather than coming up the `console.log()` part. If that's the case, any reduction can be made for the code? Thank you so much!

Comment: What do you mean by reduction, what about the code above would you like to be changed?

Comment: I'd like to change the part `document.addEventListener()`.

Comment: My code does not use `addEventListener()`